# Integral which involves an exponential function and a square root

Tags: integration

How can this integral be solved?

$$\int \frac{e^{ax}}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}dx$$

Comment: $$\int_{-b}^b\frac{e^{ax}}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}dx=\pi I_0(ab)$$

Comment: @KemonoChen, I can reduce this integral to $\int e^{c sin(\theta)}d\theta$

Comment: @KemonoChen, can u please provide a solution, to how you have obtained the bessel func.

Comment: I won't post a solution because the question is an indefinite integral. It will be off-topic. Also, the original indefinite integral seems to be No close-form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that there is a closed form for the antiderivative.

If you have to compute it (except for $\int_{-b}^b$), I would try first to let $x=b t$ which would make
$$I=\int \frac{e^{ax}}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2}}dx=\int \frac{e^{a b t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\int \frac{e^{c t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt$$ and now, use series expansion of the integrand
$$\frac{e^{c t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=1+c t+\frac{c^2+1}{2} t^2+\frac{c^3+3 c}{6} 
   t^3+\frac{c^4+6 c^2+9}{24}  t^4+\frac{c^5+10 c^3+45}{120}  t^5+O\left(t^6\right)$$ and integrate termwise.

Trying to use it for $c=1$ and integrating from $0$ to $\frac 12$, the above would give $\frac{3931}{5760}\approx 0.682465$ while numerical integration would give $0.683392$.

For sure, adding more terms will do better. Doing it with an expansion to $O\left(t^{10}\right)$ would lead to $\approx 0.683362$.

**Edit**

If I am not mistaken, for the case $c=1$, we have
$$\frac{e^{ t}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n t^n \qquad \text{with} \qquad 
\alpha_n=\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\left[(2 k-1)\text{!!}\right]^2 \binom{n}{2 k}$$

Comment: Just a question : I didn’t really see, how did you come up with that serie expansion ? I mean you use the taylor serie of e^{ct} somehow. I’m sorry if it’s obvious but I don’t see it thanks.

Comment: @Poujh. It is just the product of the Taylor series of $e^{ct}$ by  the Taylor series of $(1-t^2)^{-1/2}$, the last one being easily obtained using the binomial theorem.

Comment: Ah okay thanks !